# N: Ignoring file 'core' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension

Tags: ubuntu, segmentation-fault, apt

when running apt-get update on Ubuntu 14.04 I get the following error.

```
N: Ignoring file 'core' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
```

This happened after I added a repository:

```
apt-add-repository ppa:duplicity-team/ppa
apt-get update
(...)   
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

After this I couldn't update/upgrade packages, so I cleaned up my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and did a reboot. Now apt-get update is functional again but a file 'core' appeared in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Is this file safe to delete? This is the content of the file:

```
^?ELF^B^A^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@>^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@$
^@^@^@^@^@^@�
^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^K^@^@^@^@^@^@@W^E�^?^@^@^@^@^@^@$
^G�^?^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@$
^G�^?^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@$
^G�^?^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^@P^T^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^$
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^O�^C^@^@^@^@^@^P��^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@�Ѷ�^?^@$
^G�^?^@^@7^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@�
^G�^?^@^@^@�
^G�^?^@^@6^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@�
^G�^?^@^@^@�
^G�^?^@^@8^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@�
^G�^?^@^@^@ ^_^G�^?^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^_^G�^?^@^@^@ ?^G�^?^@^@E^A^@^@^@^@^@$
```

Answer (score 1):

That file is a [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) which was created due to the crash of apt-get update. You can safely delete it or put it by side for probable further analysis.

The fact that `apt-get update` crashes with a segfault sounds concerning. If you use an outdated version of Debian/Ubuntu I suggest to upgrade the system. If the problem then still exists I would file a bug report.